# Dropdownlist not updating inside UpdatePanel?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a asp web site. I want to update textboxes while change dropdownlist. But I don't use autopostback. Dropdownlist getting values in database and I'm writing into textbox this values.How can I do inside updatePanel?

index.aspx

```
<div class="col-sm-8">
    <asp:DropDownList ID="drp_MalAd" Width="130px" CssClass="form-control center-block" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" DataSourceID="SqlDataSourceMalAd" DataTextField="MALAD" DataValueField="MALAD" OnSelectedIndexChanged="drp_MalAd_SelectedIndexChanged"></asp:DropDownList>
    <asp:SqlDataSource runat="server" ID="SqlDataSourceMalAd" ConnectionString='<%$ ConnectionStrings:... %>' SelectCommand="SELECT ..."></asp:SqlDataSource>  
</div>
```

And My index.aspx.cs code:

```
 protected void drp_MalAd_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string malAdi = drp_MalAd.SelectedItem.Text.ToString();
    SqlDataReader reader;

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT .. WHERE MALAD='" + malAdi + "'", con);
    SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand("SELECT ...WHERE MALAD='" + malAdi + "'", con);
    SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand("SELECT ... WHERE MALAD='" + malAdi + "'", con);
    SqlCommand cmd3 = new SqlCommand("SELECT ... WHERE MALAD='" + malAdi + "'", con);

    try
    {
        con.Open();

        txt_AnaBirim.Text = cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
        txt_malKodu.Text = cmd1.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
        txt_KDVOranim.Text = cmd2.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
        con.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
    }

    try
    {
        con.Open();
        reader = cmd3.ExecuteReader();
        grd_StokDurumu.DataSource = reader;
        grd_StokDurumu.DataBind();
        reader.Close();                     
    }
    catch
    {           
    }      
    finally
    {
        con.Close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You wrap everything you want to update without a PostBack inside an `UpdatePanel`

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>

            <asp:DropDownList ID="drp_MalAd" Width="130px" CssClass="form-control center-block" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" DataSourceID="SqlDataSourceMalAd" DataTextField="MALAD" DataValueField="MALAD" OnSelectedIndexChanged="drp_MalAd_SelectedIndexChanged"></asp:DropDownList>
            <asp:SqlDataSource runat="server" ID="SqlDataSourceMalAd" ConnectionString='<%$ ConnectionStrings:... %>' SelectCommand="SELECT ..."></asp:SqlDataSource>

            <asp:TextBox ID="txt_AnaBirim" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            <asp:TextBox ID="txt_malKodu" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            <asp:TextBox ID="txt_KDVOranim" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>

    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

And you need to add a `ScriptManager` to the page.

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
```

Comment: Thank you very much